# Удалить ненужные символы в поле MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с колонками (`Column1`, `Column2`, `Column3`, `Column4`).

`Column4` принимает значения `'dasf895580000000'`, `'dasf8955sf8000sf0000'`, `'dasf8955800sf00000 абв'`, `'абв dasf89558000000sf0sf'`, `'89558000000'`.

Как удалить всё кроме цифр?
Такая проблема встречается очень часто, как создать функцию по удалению ненужных символов в поле?

Comment: В какой момент вы хотите это удалить? При заливке в БД, пройти скриптом в БД по уже лежащим данным, при чтении из БД ?

Comment: При чтении из БД.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что функцию придется делать. типа как тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378193/regex-pattern-inside-sql-replace-function  Я конечно могу попробовать придумать как это получить одним запросом, но он наверняка выйдет громоздким

Comment: А как вы читаете из БД, селектами, хранимками/вьюхами, фреймворком на другом языке парсите, обрабатываете клиентским приложением?

Comment: Я в таких случаях делал как-то так `case when len(f)>0 and isnumeric(substring(f,1,1))=1 then substring(f,1,1) else '' end + ...` это была задача отделить номер дома от буквы дома. Какая же у вас задача?

Comment: @Kromster, селектами

Comment: @nick_n_a, у меня задача вытащить номер телефона из поля (корректный номер), вся загвоздка в том, что поле Column4 принимает разные значения, как пример '8.(926)855-55-55, +7999855-33-33 #Звонил PaPA, сказал, chто приедет в 10 часов тридцать minut...' Жесть!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покажу вариант без функций (оставить только цифры) по одному case на каждую цифру.

```
select Column1, Column2, Column3, 
case when len(Column4)>0 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,1,1))=1 then substring(Column4,1,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>1 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,2,1))=1 then substring(Column4,2,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>2 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,3,1))=1 then substring(Column4,3,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>3 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,4,1))=1 then substring(Column4,4,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>4 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,5,1))=1 then substring(Column4,5,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>5 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,6,1))=1 then substring(Column4,6,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>6 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,7,1))=1 then substring(Column4,7,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>7 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,8,1))=1 then substring(Column4,8,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>8 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,9,1))=1 then substring(Column4,9,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>9 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,10,1))=1 then substring(Column4,10,1) else '' end +
case when len(Column4)>10 and isnumeric(substring(Column4,11,1))=1 then substring(Column4,11,1) else '' end  num
from table1
```

Comment: Победителя не судят, но ваш код - сплошная копипаста, сами понимаете -- это так себе код, плохо пахнет.

Comment: @AK я этот код писал сам. Пробовал всякие варианты с циклами и cross-aplly и даже xml. Я считаю свой ответ самым оптимальным, попробуйте на таблицах в 1000000 записей проверить. Я работал с адресными базами и разные методы уже опробовал.

Comment: `isnumeric('-')` и `isnumeric('+')` равны 1. Быстро - да, но не всегда корректно отработает (напр. на `+7(800)000-00-00`)

Answer (score 2):

Такое, на мой взгляд, лучше унести в CLR-функцию. На SQL тоже можно, но скорее всего будет не слишком производительно.

Функция:

```
create function tfDigitsOnly
(
    @value nvarchar(100)
)
returns table
as return
    with tally as (select top (100) N=row_number() over (order by @@spid) from sys.all_columns)
    select p.value
    from (values (@value)) v(value)
        cross apply (
            select (select C + ''
            from (select N, substring(v.value, N, 1) C from tally where N <= datalength(v.value) / 2) [1]
            where C between N'0' and N'9'
            order by N
            for xml path(''))
        ) p (value)
GO
```

(Модифицировал код, взятый [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18635337/2523686))

Пример использования:

```
declare @table table (Column4 nvarchar(100))
insert into @table values
    (N'dasf895580000000'),
    (N'dasf8955sf8000sf0000'),
    (N'dasf8955800sf00000 абв'),
    (N'абв dasf89558000000sf0sf'),
    (N'89558000000');

select d.value as Column4_CleanedUp
from @table t
    cross apply tfDigitsOnly(t.Column4) d;
```

Если символы кроме цифр представляют собой мусор, то хорошо было бы избавляться от них, ещё до попадания данных в БД. Если же символы преследуют цель форматирования (хранение номеров телефонов, например), то, мне кажется форматирование лучше унести во front-end, а в БД хранить лишь цифры.

Answer (score 2):

### С помощью функции

Добавьте функцию, которая просто будет в цикле перебирать и фильтровать цифры.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetDigits(@string nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int = 0;
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(4000) = '';
    DECLARE @char nvarchar(1);

    WHILE (@i < LEN(@string))
    BEGIN
        SET @char = SUBSTRING(@string, @i, 1);

        IF (@char >= N'0' AND @char <= N'9')
            SET @result += @char;

        SET @i += 1;
    END

    RETURN @result;
END;
```

Затем пример вызова это функции (для демонстрации)

```
SELECT dbo.GetDigits(a)
FROM 
(VALUES (N'dasf895580000000'),
    (N'dasf8955sf8000sf0000'),
    (N'dasf8955800sf00000 абв'),
    (N'абв dasf89558000000sf0sf'),
    (N'89558000000')) AS X(a);
```

Также можно создать `PERSISTED` Computed Column для этих целей, где будет вызываться функция `GetDigits`.

### Одним запросом

```
SELECT digits
FROM 
-- Примеры значений
(VALUES (N'dasf895580000000'),
    (N'dasf8955sf8000sf0000'),
    (N'dasf8955800sf00000 абв'),
    (N'абв dasf89558000000sf0sf'),
    (N'89558000000')) AS T(string)
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT STUFF( -- Используем для конкатенации строк
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(string, number, 1)
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values -- Для выборки диапазона цифр от 0 до длины строки
    WHERE type = 'P' 
        AND number < LEN(string)
        AND SUBSTRING(string, number, 1) BETWEEN N'0' AND N'9' -- Фильтруем только цифры
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE) -- Используем для конкатенации строк
.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') -- Используем для конкатенации строк
AS digits) A;
```

Comment: под частые запросы можно еще вызов функции в PERSISTED Computed Column запихнуть

Comment: @PashaPash Хорошо, я добавлю в ответ эту информацию, думаю, будет полезно.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, в функции ошибка, отсекается последняя цифра, нужно в условии цикла ставить знак не меньше, а меньше либо равно

Answer (score 2):

Рекурсивный вариант через табличное выражение одним запросом:

```
CREATE TABLE #SomeTable
(
    Id  INT,
    Field   VARCHAR(32),
    TestField   VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT #SomeTable(Id, Field)
VALUES
(1, '12fasdf453456dsfg343'),
(2, '23343455'),
(3, 'sdasdfagds'),
(4, 'fadshfhh234asd3344'),
(5 ,''),
(6, '2312fadshfhh234asd'),
(7 ,'1'),
(8 ,'g')

;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT v.Id AS Id, CAST(SUBSTRING(v.Field, PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', v.Field), 1) AS VARCHAR(32))AS symbol, 
        SUBSTRING(v.Field, PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', v.Field) + 1, LEN(v.Field) - PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', v.Field)) AS substr
    FROM #SomeTable v
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.Id, CAST(CONCAT(symbol, SUBSTRING(substr, PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', substr), 1)) AS VARCHAR(32)), 
        SUBSTRING(substr, PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', substr) + 1, LEN(substr) - PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', substr))
    FROM cte 
        JOIN #SomeTable v ON v.Id = cte.Id
    WHERE PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', substr) > 0    
)
UPDATE v
SET TestField = cte.symbol
FROM cte
    JOIN #SomeTable v ON v.Id = cte.Id
WHERE PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', substr) = 0

SELECT *
FROM #SomeTable

DROP TABLE #SomeTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку искал простой и быстрый ответ и не нашёл, оставлю его в гуглящемся вопросе для себя и других страждущих с пояснениями
Вариант для Postgresql (для MS SQL аналоги функций REPLICATE вместо REPEAT и LEN вместо length):

```
select phone, --:('A 1')
REPLACE(
    TRANSLATE(REPLACE(phone,' ','-'),                                               --заменяем пробелы в строке на '-': ('A-1')
    TRANSLATE(REPLACE(phone,' ','-'),'1234567890','----------'),                    --заменяем все цифры на '-': (A--)
    REPEAT('-',length(TRANSLATE(REPLACE(phone,' ','-'),'1234567890','----------'))) --генерим такую же строку из '-': (---)
)                                               --заменяем все оставшиеся символы и '-' в оригинальной строке на '-' ('A-1' -> '--1')
,'-','')                                        -- Удаляем все дефисы ('--1' -> '1')
 from 
 (select 'ТелеФон :+7 (815) 021-14- 18//' as phone) as bs
```

Без функций и в одну операцию. И работает очень быстро.